# Simple power supply circuit loses voltage over time

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, transformer

I have a simple [circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+69.34413510434165+56+5+43%0Ad+80+240+160+160+1+0.805904783%0Ad+160+160+240+240+1+0.805904783%0Ad+80+240+160+320+1+0.805904783%0Ad+160+320+240+240+1+0.805904783%0Av+-32+320+-32+160+0+1+60+18+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-32+160+-32+112+0%0Aw+-32+112+160+112+0%0Aw+160+112+160+160+0%0Aw+-32+320+-32+368+0%0Aw+-32+368+160+368+0%0Aw+160+368+160+320+0%0Aw+80+240+80+448+0%0Aw+80+448+240+448+0%0Aw+240+448+384+448+0%0Aw+240+240+384+240+0%0A209+240+240+240+448+0+0.00009999999999999999+17.444855153861447+1%0Ar+384+240+384+352+0+10000000%0Ar+384+352+384+448+0+680000%0Aw+384+352+480+352+0%0Aw+384+448+480+448+0%0Ar+480+352+480+448+0+1000000000%0Ao+20+64+0+4099+1.25+0.00009765625+0+2+20+3%0Ao+16+64+0+4099+20+0.00009765625+1+2+16+3%0Ao+17+64+0+4099+5+0.00009765625+2+2+17+3%0A) that I built from a 120V to 18V transformer, a [bridge rectifier](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Shindengen/D3SBA60-7000?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtQ8nqTKtFS%2FO3Fk435D9dkhChyppACtWs%3D) and a few passives. I have a voltage divider because my little $20 oscilloscope can only handle max 12V. I expect to see around 1.1 Vout, and sure enough I do. But then I went to the bathroom and when I came back the multimeter read 0.8V. So then I let it sit for a while, and the value keeps going down. If I unplug it and plug it back in, I start at 1.1V again. The transformer (which I salvaged from a broken UPS) gets warm, but doesn't seem to be alarmingly hot or anything. So I'm stumped.

My guess is that it has something to do with the RC portion of the circuit, relatively high resistance in the divider interacting with the cap somehow that I don't get, but I'm not finding anything online about it. Searching doesn't give me what I want because results for step-down transformers seem to get in the way.

Am I doing something dangerously wrong? Will I accidentally burn down my apartment?

Comment: Are you sure your oscilloscope is 1 \$G\Omega\$? Typically scopes have a 1 or 10 \$M\Omega\$ impedance (1x or 10x probe),  so it may have something to do with that. You might try reducing the resistance of your divider, maybe to something like 100k//6.8k?

Comment: Total speculation here, but if everything else is sound, maybe the transformer is getting saturated (with magnetic field).  I don't know why this would happen over an hour.

Comment: We need to see a complete schematic with component values.

Comment: The component values are in the circuit schematic/simulation.

Comment: @C_Elegans My scope and multimeter are almost certainly of impedance $< 1G \Omega$, the load value is somewhat arbitrary (I originally had an op-amp in mind). But is there any mathematical reason that such values would lead to a long term voltage drop?